# Make dynamic sql to get data from session array

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am using PDO. I want to make a sql statement which gives the `user_id`  of that user which name is in session array. When I get the data from session array in variable and write it in sql it gives nothing but when I write "jhon" it gives `user_id` that I required. But I want to dynamic sql prepare statement.  I see some solution from net but I can't figure it out.

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["username"])){
    $name=$_SESSION["username"];
    function  add_posts(){
        if($posts_text != ""){
            try {
                $conn=parent::connect();    
                $sql1=$conn->prepare("select user_id from user_login 
                                      where username=:username ");
                $arr=array ('username'=>$name );//when i write "jhon" it gives id 14,
                //  when i write $name it gives nothing
                $sql1->execute($arr);  
                $fetch = $sql1->fetch();

                echo $fetch['user_id'];
            }
            catch (PDOException $e){
                die ("connection failed" .$e->getMessage() );
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes it gives correct value "jhon".

Answer (score 2):

You need you pass `$name` argument in your function

```
 function add_posts($name) {
```

Comment: Use `print` and `die()` to find out error and check where your code break!!

Comment: And have you close this if condition `if(isset($_SESSION["username"])){`

Comment: mycode is right because when i  i give username =>"jhon"  in array it gives id=14 . butt when i gives username=>$name it gives nothing

Comment: Check the value of `$name=$_SESSION["username"];`

Comment: echo $name;      it gives "jhon"

Comment: it  cheks that post  textarea is empty or not? when user clicks on ost button